# Win8 in Active Directory - remove Apps

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

We have a joined a Win8 Client for the first time to our AD. Before doing so, I removed all uneccessary Apps and Programs which came pre-installed. We have no clean deployable image for this time. After Domain joining and login with a domain user the apps reappeared on the start screen?
How can I remove the unwanted stuff permanently? Is there a group policy for controlling the apps?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Is it even possible to manage these apps per GPO with a domain functional level 2003?

Comment: Do you mean shortcuts in start menu or installed applications?

Comment: I mean "apps" in the start screen. SkyDrive, Music and the like. Most of them don't show up in "Programs and Features". Also there where some Programs showing up there, I removed them from "Programs and Features" but they seemed not completely removed and can still be executed from the start screen after login with my domain account (they a re gone for the local account).

Comment: If you dont have GPO policy that runs those installers (i presume you dont) you should check All Users profile (start menu) for those shortcuts and delete them from there.

Comment: There a several people which will use this machine, so I want to do it with GPO or other automated mechanism. Edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you use DISM to remove the packages?

```
dism /mount-wim /wimfile:%WIM% /mountdir:%MOUNTDIR% /index:1
dism /Image:%MOUNTDIR% /Remove-Provisionedappxpackage /PackageName:Microsoft.BingFinance_1.2.0.135_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /Image:%MOUNTDIR% /Remove-Provisionedappxpackage /PackageName:Microsoft.BingMaps_1.2.0.136_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /Image:%MOUNTDIR% /Remove-Provisionedappxpackage /PackageName:Microsoft.BingNews_1.2.0.135_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /Image:%MOUNTDIR% /Remove-Provisionedappxpackage /PackageName:Microsoft.BingSports_1.2.0.135_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /Image:%MOUNTDIR% /Remove-Provisionedappxpackage /PackageName:Microsoft.BingTravel_1.2.0.145_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /Image:%MOUNTDIR% /Remove-Provisionedappxpackage /PackageName:Microsoft.BingWeather_1.2.0.135_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /Image:%MOUNTDIR% /Remove-Provisionedappxpackage /PackageName:Microsoft.Bing_1.2.0.137_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /Image:%MOUNTDIR% /Remove-Provisionedappxpackage /PackageName:Microsoft.Camera_6.2.8514.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /Image:%MOUNTDIR% /Remove-Provisionedappxpackage /PackageName:microsoft.microsoftskydrive_16.4.4204.712_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /Image:%MOUNTDIR% /Remove-Provisionedappxpackage /PackageName:Microsoft.Reader_6.2.8516.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /Image:%MOUNTDIR% /Remove-Provisionedappxpackage /PackageName:microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_16.4.4206.722_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /Image:%MOUNTDIR% /Remove-Provisionedappxpackage /PackageName:microsoft.windowsphotos_16.4.4204.712_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /Image:%MOUNTDIR% /Remove-Provisionedappxpackage /PackageName:Microsoft.XboxLIVEGames_1.0.927.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /Image:%MOUNTDIR% /Remove-Provisionedappxpackage /PackageName:Microsoft.ZuneMusic_1.0.927.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /Image:%MOUNTDIR% /Remove-Provisionedappxpackage /PackageName:Microsoft.ZuneVideo_1.0.927.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
dism /unmount-wim /mountdir:%MOUNTDIR% /commit
```

Also, you should be able to load the ADMX files on your current domain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer? No I didn't used DISM. I just tapped on it longer and tapped "Remove"....

Comment: What you did above seems to me would only remove the icon from the Start Screen or "uninstall" it for a single user.

To completely remove the apps you need to uninstall them from the WIM using the DISM command line. I would familiarize yourself with this utility: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744256(WS.10).aspx

Comment: You may also be interested in this if your goal is to customize the Start Screen, rather than uninstall the default apps. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134269

Comment: Thanks. For removing the apps directly on the machine I did `dism /online /Remove-Provisionedappxpackage /PackageName:<PackageName>`. The Apps still appear for the account I logged in with first, but not for new accounts.

Comment: If you run dism offline on the WIM before deploying your image it will be completely removed for everyone.